# How do i implement a working if Statement in twig? mine isnt working

Tags: if-statement, twig

im trying to do a simple IF statement while templating with twig. Appears that it gets ignored and the following code is read everytime. Should be Pretty simple but does just not work.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="box">
{% set x = 1 %}

    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
        {% if x % 3 == 0 %}
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% set x =+ 1 %}
        <div class="beitrag col l4 m12 s12">
            <h3 class="beitrag_titel">{{ entry.title }}</h3> <p>{{ entry.textnews }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

i want the code to do a new "row" div every third entry. All he does is do a new one every time.

thx for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment of `x` is wrong. there is no postincrement in `twig`.
At this point your just setting `x` to `+1` every time. You should be using `{% set x = x + 1 %}`

---

Some notes, it not necessary to keep track of an extra counter in the for loop as you could use `loop.index` or `loop.index0`, starting at 1 and 0 respectively.

Also you could use the test `is divisible by` for more readability

```html
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {% if loop.index is divisible by(3) %}
        {{ loop.index }} is divisible by 3
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/i2ds2q)

---

To solve html issues with rows you could also use [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

```html
<div class="box">
{% for row in data|batch(3) %}
    {% for value in row %}
    <div class="beitrag col l4 m12 s12">
            {{ value }}
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="row"></div>
{% endfor %}    
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/5upoh4)

---

From your (deleted) comment, if you wanted the content to go inside the `row`, u 'd need to adapt the code as following

```html
    <div class="box">
        {% set x = 1 %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            {% if loop.first %}
            <div class="row">
            {% endif %}
                <div class="col l4 m12 s12">
                    <h3 class="beitrag_titel">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ entry.textnews }}</p>
                </div>
            {% if x is divisible by(3) and not loop.last %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            {% endif %}
            {% set x = x + 1 %}
            {% if loop.last and entries|length is not divisible by(3)  %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/jhswx1)

But then you are def better of with batch

```html
<div class="box">
{% for row in entries|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for value in row %}
        <div class="beitrag col l4 m12 s12">
            <h3>{{ value.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ value.textnews }}</p>
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}    
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/jhswx1/2)

Comment: @regrettableclone0816 updated answer to reflect your comment

Comment: Batch works well now. Huge thank you!

had to adjust some Things though. there was a Problem with variables

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news')|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for value in entry %}`